# Counting number of documents in an index in elasticsearch

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, elasticsearch

I'm doing a bulk operation to index 100 documents at once using the python ElasticSearch Client. I want to count the total number of documents in an index. So I do the bulk op and then count the number of documents in an index as below:

```
helpers.bulk(es_client, actions);
es_client.count('index').get('count')
```

However the second line still returns the old count, and I tried to run the second line from a different file, which returns the correct result. I suspect that bulk op is not yet completed. Please correct me if I'm wrong, and what would be the workaround to do what I want?

Comment: Apparently documents added with bulk operation are not yet considered for that index refreshing the index before getting the count fixed the problem.

Answer (score 20):

get the index document count in python

```
es.indices.refresh(index_name)
es.cat.count(index_name, params={"format": "json"})
```

Comment: The `count` function returns a `ListApiResponse`, so to get the integer value of the count you need to access `int(res[0]["count"])` where `res` is the result of `es.cat.count`.

Answer (score 8):

I found this in the examples that I attach below

```
es=Elasticsearch([{'host':'url','port':'9200','timeout':60}]) 
res = es.count(index='your index', doc_type='your doc_type', body={'query': your query })["count"]
```

If it helps you, here are good examples of count with Python:

https://python.hotexamples.com/examples/elasticsearch/Elasticsearch/count/python-elasticsearch-count-method-examples.html

Answer (score 5):

You have to use `refresh` API:

`POST /index/_refresh`

> The refresh API allows to explicitly refresh one or more index, making all operations performed since the last refresh available for search. The (near) real-time capabilities depend on the index engine used. For example, the internal one requires refresh to be called, but by default a refresh is scheduled periodically.

For more info look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html